# Guardar valor automaticamente con un UpdateView Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Me gustaría saber como podría usar los métodos y/o sobrescritura de vistas basadas en clases para que después de actualizar un objeto se le asigne un valor a un campo de mi modelo. Por ejemplo creé una UpdateView en la que cierto usuario podría asignar a una persona para realizar un reporte y lo que me gustaría, es que después de haber realizado esa actualización, el valor del campo "estatus" sea "Asignado".

Esta es la vista que estoy usando de la UpdateView para cualquier referencia:

```
class reporteupdate(UpdateView):
model = reporte_fallo
form_class = ReporteAsignar
template_name = 'formulario/jefe_asignar.html'
success_url = reverse_lazy('formulario:reporte_listar_jefe')
```

Comment: y este campo "estatus" esta en el mismo modelo "reporte_fallo"

Answer (score 0):

Debes sobrescribir el método `form_valid`:

```py
class reporteupdate(UpdateView):
    model = reporte_fallo
    form_class = ReporteAsignar
    template_name = 'formulario/jefe_asignar.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('formulario:reporte_listar_jefe')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super().form_valid(form)

        form.instance.MI_CAMPO = "MI VALOR"
        form.instance.save()

        return response
```